# Select element arrow image disappears on selection

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to create a custom (to a degree) dropdown box (select) element

It looks ok until I click the dropdown, then the arrow disappears

the css and html are as follow:

```css
.styled_select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(/images_/icons/down_arrow_select.jpg) no-repeat right #ddd;
 }

 select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 233px;
    height:34px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color:#666;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="styled_select">
    <select name="reason">
   <option value=1>1</option>
   <option value=2>2</option>
   <option value=3>3</option>
   <option value=4>4</option>
 </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: seems to work for me on firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/FhVJs/1/

Comment: @Alex thanks for that - need to look closely at the rest of CSS i guess... hmmm